# Mocha: bail on one specific describe only

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, mocha.js, chai

I use mocha/chai to test my graphql endpoints for a nodejs/express server - which works fine. However, in the first test, I check if any .env variables have been set correctly.
If not, all further tests will be affected anyways. So I would like to terminate all further tests when any test in this block fails (preferably finishing the block to capture all 'missing' variables).

So can I somehow terminate the entire test, when a certain describe-block fails?

Note: I found the bail flag/config option, but this determines the whole test on any error, which is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can try add `after` hook and add a condition there

```
after('Fail for some describe', function () {
            if(this.test.parent.title.startsWith('Describe title that should fail') && this.test.parent.isFailed())
                this.test.parent._bail = true
        });
```

This could be tricky since `this` context may contain several layers of parents so if not sure you can always log the keys for current `this.test` object. Also, bear in mind that the following describe might have different `this` context with overriden `_bail` value. This solution is good when it comes to tracking specific critical `it` failures.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
beforeEach(function() {
    if ( this.currentTest.parent.tests.some(test => test.state === "failed") )
        this.skip(); // Skip subsequent tests if the describe block failed
});
```

All subsequent tests will be skipped in the describe block that has this before each hook.